# Audio not working Macbook Air 3,2 Nvidia MCP89

Tags: 11.04, sound, macbook

I've upgraded to ubuntu 11.04 and since then the audio stopped working (I was on 10.10 before that).

I'm using a Macbook Air 3,2 and these are details of my audio card:

```
         description: Audio device
         product: MCP89 High Definition Audio
         vendor: nVidia Corporation
         physical id: 8
         bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
         version: a2
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
```

It doesn't work either with headphones or speakers.

Alsa mixer doesn't show anything muted and all the volumes are up.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744775&page=2

I've just uninstalled the package snd-hda-dkms, rebooted and the audio worked again.